# Настройка маршрутизации по двум провайдерам на виртуальной машине

Tags: сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация, виртуальная-машина

Пытаюсь настроить сеть, имеется два провайдера.
Виртуальная машина debian 9.0.

Первый провайдер подключен напрямую, имеет ip 58.xxx.xxx.246.
На виртуалке первый интерфейс настроен под первого провайдера.
могу извне подключиться через ssh по заданному ip.

Второй провайдер подключен через роутер имеет ip 70.xxx.xxx.71. на роутере настроил dhcp, назначил MAC(второго интерфейса виртуалки) для локального ip 192.168.2.111.

Firewall настроил. Т.е. когда обращаюсь на 70.xxx.xxx.71 port 22, он переадресовывал на 192.168.2.111 port 22.
Локально на виртуалку могу подключиться через ssh по ip 192.168.2.111.
извне не могу, как я понимаю нужно настроить маршруты на виртуалке

```
вот что показывает ip route list table main

default via 58.xxx.xxx.245 dev eno2 onlink
10.0.0.0/24 dev vmbr1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
58.xxx.xxx.244/30 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 58.xxx.xxx.246
192.168.2.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.111

ip a

2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:1c:11:63:58:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.111/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eno1
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:35:1a:63:9c:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 58.xxx.xxx.246/30 brd 58.xxx.xxx.247 scope global eno2

когда выполняю 
route add default gw 192.168.2.1 metric 0
route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 58.xxx.xxx.245 metric 0
```

то не могу зайти по ssh через 58.xxx.xxx.246(первого провайдера)
но могу зайти по ssh через 70.xxx.xxx.71(второго провайдера)

```
создал таблицы маршрутизации
echo '10 t1' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo '11 t2' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

после добавлений правил маршрутизации вообще локально не могу подключиться, приходится ребутить виртуалку.

```
Правила которые я добавляю
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 table T1
ip rule add from 192.168.2.110 table T1
ip route add 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table T1

ip route add default via 58.xxx.xxx.246 table T2
ip rule add from 58.xxx.xxx.245 table T2
ip route add 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table T2
```

Нужно чтобы я мог обращаться по 58.xxx.xxx.246 и по 70.xxx.xxx.71, и мог заходить по ssh.

В сетевом администрировании я полный ноль, поэтому за текст выше я извиняюсь, т.к. я даже не совсем понимаю что я делаю.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

получилось настроить маршруты данным способом.

```
ip route add 192.168.2.1 dev eno1 src 192.168.2.111 table T1
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 table T1
ip route add 58.xxx.xxx.245 dev eno2 src 58.xxx.xxx.246 table T2
ip route add default via 58.xxx.xxx.246 table T2    
ip route add 192.168.2.1 dev eno1 src 192.168.2.110
ip route add 58.xxx.xxx.245 dev eno2 src 58.xxx.xxx.246
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
ip rule add from 192.168.2.110 table T1
ip rule add from 58.xxx.xxx.246 table T2
```

После этого мог коннектится по ssh по данным ip адресам без проблем.